# How to convert `Multiple words` into `multiple-words as "Multiple words"`?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Say I have a text:

```
Multiple words
In yellow and in blue
```

How can I make it to this?

```
multiple-words as "Multiple words" 
in-yellow-and-in-blue as "In yellow and in blue"
```

So far my best try is this:

- Find: `(.*)`
- Replace: `-\1- as "\1"`

To have it in the form of `-Multiple words- as "Multiple words"`. The `-` is to mark the boundary easier. But I can't tell it to only replace the spaces in between the boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in several steps:

1. Search for `^.*$` and replace with `$& as "$&"`: it just wraps all lines with quotes.
2. Search for `(?:\G|^\S*)\K\h+(?=.* as ".*"$)` and replace with `-`: it replaces all horizontal whitespaces  (`\h`) from the start of the line till a `as "..."` pattern.
3. Search for `(?:\G-|^)[^-]+(?=\S* as ".*"$)` and replace with `\L$&`: it will turn to lowercase all chunks of non-hyphen chars from the start of string till `as "..."` pattern.

Note `\L`, `\U` and other case changing operators do not work with non-ASCII letters in Notepad++.